# Filter apps that is not launch-able with PackageInfo class android

Tags: android

i able to get list of all the apps from system with PackageInfo class (mention code below ).
i am getting both system as well as installed but apart from that, i am getting system apps that cant be launch like installer,wallpaper,media storage.
i want to filter this kind of apps and want to show apps that can be launch only like default stock android Launcher shows.

```
private List<PackageInfoLocal> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PackageInfoLocal> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfoLocal>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PackageInfoLocal newInfo = new PackageInfoLocal();
        newInfo.appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.packageName = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;

        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
        try {
            applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(p.packageName, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file = new File(applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
        long size = file.length();


        float fileSizeInKB = size / 1024;

        newInfo.size = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
        newInfo.longsize=newInfo.size;
        newInfo.size=(float) (Math.round(newInfo.size*100.0)/100.0);
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        if(!newInfo.appName.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.app_name))){
            res.add(newInfo);
        }
    }
    return res;

}
```

Comment: `pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)` where `intent` is like this: `intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);`

Comment: @pskink sorry misspelling, its not working . i still getting un-launchable apps also .

Comment: un-launchable? like what?

Comment: @pskink like Mobile Data, Media Storage,External Storage,HTML Viewer, Mms service,config updater ,MusicFx.i want to eliminate this type of apps/service

Comment: what is the size of the list? and how many icons do you have in your launcher? post the code you are using

Comment: @pskink I have 70(system+installed) apps in my device .the data i am getting with above code with i am getting 141 apps in my listview

Comment: and your code is? and what launcher are you using? some 3rd party, custom one?

Comment: my code i have mention in question itself and creating launcher for just to know launcher works .mine launcher showing 141 apps and stock google launcher showing 70

Comment: use this: `pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)`

Comment: tried not working  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1unttnj5cymwof/Screenshot_2015-08-20-22-20-34.png?dl=0

Comment: what not working??? post the code you have tried

Comment: @pskink you can see that code in question that is returning list of apps .and this is screenshot my app https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1unttnj5cymwof/Screenshot_2015-08-20-22-20-34.png?dl=0

Comment: @pskink the code that i have is not diffrent that above . i just added the         Intent mintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        mintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);           pm.queryIntentActivities(mintent,0);

Comment: is it the output same like this: http://codeshare.io/QHZhf

Comment: @pskink i am getting application error with above link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i1ZdpT21

Comment: @pskink http://pastebin.com/gGvmXwLL i am understanding with field will be useful from List<ResolveInfo> to sort apps.i have gone through Log but not able to find

Comment: so what is `xxx` in the logcat: `onCreate mi.size() == xxx` ?

Comment: @pskink i am getting 70 in log cat. what you want to tell with that ,whats the use of that.how can i use your code to sort apps

Comment: so you have 70 "launchable" Activities and they are stored in `List<ResolveInfo> mi`, and why are you saying: "queryIntentActivities is not working" ???

Comment: @pskink so you want me create loop of size (List<ResolveInfo>) and save all apps data into another list and display the saved data   into listview

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: refer my code http://pastebin.com/gGvmXwLL

Comment: in code at the end i have  " if " state .there i am saving app info into list.that list size is  141 .i want to sort that list so that it will not show unlaunchable  app

Comment: i gave you a working code, if you don't want to use it but insist to use your code its ok, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent mintent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(p.packageName);
```

if "mintent" is not null then its launchable app
where p is PackageInfo object.